# How to pass a function as a parameter to a class in python

Tags: python, oop

I want to pass a function to a class when I initialize it. Here's a toy example I came up with and it works:

```
def addition(self):
        return self.a + self.b


def multiplication(self):
    return self.a * self.b


class Test:

    def __init__(self, a, b, fcn):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.fcn = fcn

t = Test(3, 3, addition)

print t.fcn(t)

t = Test(3, 3, multiplication)

print t.fcn(t)
```

Is it possible to simply call `t.fcn()` as you would any other class method?

Comment: I dont get it. why the -1? It was a question! And I found an answer. Isnt that the point?

Comment: I'm guessing the -1 is because this is an easily test-able answer. By putting it in your terminal you'd find that yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Imagine: If you put it in the terminal, you will find that `t.fcn()` throws an error.

Comment: Well that's because he's not calling it right. If t.fcn was print, then it would be fine, or if he called t.fcn(3, 3) then it would be fine too. But I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try it?

the answer is yes

```
def do_op(x,y,fn):
   return fn(x,y)

def add(a,b):
   return a+b

print do_op(5,4,add)
```

same with a class

```
class whatever:
      def __init__(self,fn):
         self.fn = fn
      def do_it(self,*args,**kwargs):
         return self.fn(*args,**kwargs)
         #if you wanted the fn to have self as the first argument
         #return self.fn(self,*args,**kwargs) #just pass self as first argument

x = whatever(add)
print x.do_it(5,8)
```

further along what you are asking for (if im reading it right)

```
def add(self):
   return self.a + self.b

class whatever:
      def __init__(self,fn,a,b):
         self.__dict__[fn.__name__] = fn
         self.a,self.b = a,b
      def do_it(self):
         return self.fn(self)

x = whatever(add,6,7)
x.do_it()
```

or perhaps you want something like

```
from functools import partial
def add(self):
   return self.a + self.b
class whatever:
      def __init__(self,fn,a,b):
         self.__dict__[fn.__name__] = partial(fn,self)
         self.a,self.b = a,b

x = whatever(add,5,6)
x.add()
```

this kind of introspection is somewhat risky in deployed code ...

Comment: The function doesn't have access to `self` if you do it this way, though.

Comment: @user2357112 yes ... but that was not part of the question ... you can certainly give it self as the first arg if you want ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: But then you're in exactly the situation the OP already has with his example code.

Comment: @Chet is that last example what you are asking for?